# Use custom Service inside Custom Event

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning Symfony and I'm trying to create: a new service and Event

My service send emails

config.yml

```
parameters:
    MyService.class:      Acme\UserBundle\Services\sendEmail
    MyService.transport:  sendmail
```

service.yml

```
services:
    MyService:
        class:        %MyService.class%
        arguments:    [@mailer]
```

sendEmail.php

```
class sendEmail {

    private $mail;

    public function __construct ($mail) {
        $this->mail = $mail;
    }

    public function sendMail () {
        $msg = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Hi')
            ->setFrom('xxx@example.com')
            ->setTo('cc@gmail.com')
            ->setBody('ok');
        $this->mail->send($msg);
    }


}
```

My Event

I have created these class

```
UserEvent.php
    <?php
    namespace Acme\UserBundle\Event;


    final class UserEvents {

        const NEW_USER='new.user';


    }
```

newUserEvent.php

```
<?php

/**
 * EVENT DISPATCHER
 */
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Event;

use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;


class NewUserEvent extends Event {

    protected $user;

    public function __construct (User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser () {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

newUserListener.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Event;
use Acme\UserBundle\Services\sendEmail;    

class NewUserListener {

    public function sendEmailToUsers(NewUserEvent $event,sendEmail $service)
    {
        // ... send email to users
    }
}
```

in my controller

```
$em = $this->getEm();

        $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

        // attach listener
        $listner = new NewUserListener();
        $dispatcher->addListener(UserEvents::NEW_USER,array($listner,'sendEmailToUsers'));

        $user = $em->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('username' => 'alex')); //mock
        $event = new NewUserEvent($user,$this->get('MyService'));
        $dispatcher->dispatch(UserEvents::NEW_USER,$event);



        return new Response('hi');
```

I'd like to use my service inside my event by I have this error

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   Acme\UserBundle\Event\NewUserListener::sendEmailToUsers() must be an
>   instance of Acme\UserBundle\Services\sendEmail, none given in
>   Acme/UserBundle/Event/NewUserListener.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many points here :

- You create a new event dispatcher in your controller, but the event dispatcher service is already available in a standard Symfony app, you should use it and register your listener with the kernel.event_listener tag for your service :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

```
$disptacher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');
```

- Secondly, nowhere you inject your service in your listener ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm Following this doc http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html#creating-and-dispatching-an-event for create Event. I have to use KernelEvents ? How can i inject my service in my listener ? thanks again

Comment: You should declare your listener as a service and as argument pass your sendEmail service.

Comment: Ok I will try, I have to modify only my listener, because my service SendEmail works. Then, Anytime that i want a service inside my listener, i have to create listener as service? thank you

Comment: Yes globally you need to define somewhere what to inject in your listener. Best practice is listener as a service.

Comment: Ok, but which event of kernel I have to choose? http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/KernelEvents.html. I don't want, for example, call my listener for each Request, But only After Persist new User. thanks again

Comment: to which event you want to listen ? new.user I guess. kernel.event_listener does not mean events are specific to the kernel, only that your listener is registered in the kernel.